# How to change mongodb field datatype from NumberLong to Double?

Tags: mongodb, double, type-conversion

How do I change mongodb field datatype from NumberLong to Double?

I've tried without success:

```
db.getCollection('mycoll').find({'_id':10150097174480591}).forEach( function (x) { 
    x._id = new Double(x._id);
    db.getCollection('mycoll').save(x);
});
```

Comment: The `_id` field is immutable. You'd have to create new documents with the new `_id`.

Answer (score 1):

The "type" of the object needs to be recast. Better in Bulk, and filter out with [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/):

```js
var bulk = db.users2.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.mycoll.find({ "_id": { "$type": 18 } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc._id = parseInt(doc._id.valueOf());
    bulk.insert(doc);
    count++;       

    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.users2.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Note that because this is `_id` you need another collection. If you try to do with other fields and within the same collection, then you need to remove and "reset" the field in the document in order to effect the change:

```js
var bulk = db.mycoll.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.mycoll.find({ "a": { "$type": 18 } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.a = parseInt(doc.a.valueOf());
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$unset": { "a": "" }
    });
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "a": doc.a }
    });

    count++;       

    if ( count % 500 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.mycoll.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if ( count % 500 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```